# Adding columns as a background

Tags: html, css

This is my app:
http://www.aproov.com/product/meeting-demo/index.html

The container holding the widgets is a div and each widget is actually made up of a li element inside a  element.

What I would like to have are 4 background columns inside the container that extend from the top of the container to the bottom and are filled in with a color. Currently, you can drag the widgets around by clicking on their header text.

I'm not sure of the best solution to add the columns. The width of each column is the width of the widget. At first, I thought maybe I could add a a div table inside the container and somehow make the  element stuff just "float" on top of it. That seems kind of complex though. Another solution is to use HTML5 canvas and just draw the columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just be creating your background columns as `div`s with 100% height and 25% width and putting them inside a parent `div` that is 100% height and width, and absolutely positioned at 0,0 in your main container div. Something like:

```
<div id="container"> <!-- main container -->
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

#container > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#container > div > div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```